# Working with Switches in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

im a newbie in iOS Programming (i know java) and i have trouble with a simple UISwitch. I have a Tab-based Application with two Views. First View: Data (Single View). Second View:Settings (TableView).

I started with creating some UILabels on my First view and with some TableView Cells in the Settings-view. Now i just want that when a Switch (which is in a table view cell) is on, a label on the first View should say "YES", else "no". Just something really simple.

My question is: How can i get access on my UISwitch in the FirstView.m? I imported the SecondView.h already. But how can my FirstView get access to all the stuff from the SecondView?

I searched on google and found : `SecondViewController secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];`

I set the StoryboardID of my SecondView to secondView. But it doesn't work.

Can someone help me please?

EDIT:

Here is a my Code:

FirstViewController View did appear Method:

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    BOOL onOff = secondView.mySwitch.on;
    if (onOff){
        label.text = @"On";
    }
    else{
        label.text = @"Off";
    }
}
```

Here is the viewDidLoad of my FirstVIew

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
}
```

in my .h file i created a property

```
@property SecondViewController *secondView;
```

And in the .m file i @synthesize it.

I'm sure that i set the Storyboard ID, because when i type in something different, the program doesnt even start.

in the SecondViewController.h i added the Switch

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
```

I added it by drag it into the source code with a right click.

So it seems that i dont get access to the class

**+++++++++++++++++ EDIT2: ++++++++++++++++++++++++**

This is my complete Project. Basically it is just the Tabbed Template, with a UITableView as the Second View. FirstView is a singleView. So here is my project:

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSwitch;
@property SecondViewController *secondView;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize secondView, lblSwitch;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (secondView.mySwitch.isOn){

        NSLog(@"First View: Switch is on!");
        lblSwitch.text = @"Switch is on!";

    }
    else {

    NSLog(@"First View: Switch is off!");
    lblSwitch.text = @"Switch is off!";

    }


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize mySwitch;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (mySwitch.isOn) NSLog(@"Switch is on");
    else NSLog(@"Switch is off");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

That is all the code. Here is a screenshot of the main.storyboard
[Here is the Photo](http://postimg.org/image/knnrsv89h/)

Comment: What you are doing is correct. And you would need to expose the stuffs you want to get access to in .h file in the SecondView. Ex: `@property (strong, nonatomic) UISwitch *mySwitch;`

Comment: I already connected The Switch with my Code Using The storyboard(Right click, drag..). But i think the First view still doesnt know The Second view. I tried this in The viewdidload : if (sencondview.switchON) lbl.text="on" .. And it doesnt work.

Comment: If you are using this line: `SecondViewController secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];` like you wrote, a * is missing right before "secondView = ..."

Comment: Xcode gave me The Solution with * , but it still doesnt work. What Else could be the problem?

Comment: @user2710855 Try my answer and see if anything appears in the console

Comment: First: make sure you did set up the storyboard ID in Storyboard for your secondViewController. Second: if you come from the Java world, how would you get access to an instance variable in class B from class A? What would you do in class A? Same scenario here.

Comment: @Unheilig i checked the storyboard ID and it is correct. in java i would create a getter-method and `SecondViewController secondView = new SecondViewController()` -> `secondView.switchOn()`.  But it still doesnt work.. i can access my switch now by `secondView.switch.isOn` , but it doesnt check if its on.. i tried it with a if-statement. so my view did appear method is: `if (secondView.switch.isOn) NSLOG(On) else NSLog (Off);`. And it always shows: "off"

Comment: i updated my first post with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post 2 classes for you here:

Just copy and paste it.

**SwitchViewController.h (Your First View Controller)**

```
@class LabelViewController;
@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
- (IBAction)switch:(id)sender; 
//connect the above from storyboard.
@property (strong, nonatomic) LabelViewController *secondView;

@end
```

**SwitchViewController.m**

```
#import "SwitchViewController.h"
#import "LabelViewController.h"

@interface SwitchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SwitchViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)switch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch*) sender;
    [self addChildViewController:self.secondView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.secondView.view];
    self.secondView.myLabel.text = (theSwitch.isOn ? @"On" : @"Off");
}
@end
```

**LabelViewController.h (Your Second View Controller)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LabelViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backToFirstView;
- (IBAction)backToFirstView:(id)sender; 
//connect the above from storyboard.
@end
```

**LabelViewController.m**

```
#import "LabelViewController.h"

@interface LabelViewController ()

@end

@implementation LabelViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backToFirstView:(id)sender
{
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"If it works, buy me a beer.");
}
@end
```

In Storyboard: Create 2 `UIViewControllers`.
While you are there, set Storyboard ID for `LabelViewController` as **secondView**.

Here is a screenshot of storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

`SUPER EDIT:`

There are two classes and a snapshot of storyboard.

Your firstView (the one with Label as `IBOutlet`)

In **YourFirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourFirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

In **YourFirstViewCntroller.m**

```
#import "YourFirstViewController.h"
#import "YourTableViewController.h"

@interface YourFirstViewController ()

@property(strong, nonatomic) YourTableViewController *tableView;

@end

@implementation YourFirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will appear in first view");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.myLabel.text = (self.tableView.mySwitsch.isOn ? @"ON" : @"OFF");
}
```

In **YourTableViewController.h** (in which you have an `IBOutlet` for your switch)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitsch;
@end
```

In **YourTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will apear table view");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load in table view");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.mySwitsch];
    }
// Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

[image: storyboard snap shot]

***** Super Super Edit *****

If you want to keep your `UINavigation Controller` around:

In your **first view controller.m**

Replace it with the following in your `viewDidLoad':

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    self.tableView = (YourTableViewController*) [self.navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

Add a property `@property(strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;`

```
Tested.
```

Comment: thank you, i will try that out later. but does it make a difference when im jusing a UITableView with Static Cells instead of a normal View?

Comment: i finally had time to try your code. i checked your code, and checked whats different to my code. then i changed my code. but it still doesnt work. I'm using a single view as the first view, and a UITableView as the second view. and i have a tab based app. does this make any difference? OffTopic: Are you german? because of your name.

Comment: ich habe mein Beitrag editiert. Ich habe jetzt das komplette Projekt gepostet. Gruß

Comment: i don't really get it. i created a property UITabBarController and named it myTabBar. then i created a property `SecondViewController secondView;` . After that i typed in `myTabBar = [self.str .. initwith... "tabBar"];` . then i have to link it to the second view right? like: `secondView = myTabBar.viewControllers[1];` ... Is that how you mean it? I tried it like this but i get this error: " unrecognized selector sent to instance" ... Thanks!

Comment: Please comment in English since only you and me and maybe a few other users understand it but the vast majority of users does *not* speak German so these comments are not useful for them at all ... And German sucks btw ;)

Comment: thanks for your response. when i edit my project and make it look like yours, i get plenty of error messages when i press the run button. so can you upload the project anywhere maybe? so i can check where is my (little) error.

Comment: `[UINavigationController mySwitsch]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` .. thats the error.

Comment: @user2710855 I read your comment at first in German. But since German schucks ;-), let's do it in whatever :-). Ok, in my solution, I bumped off `UINavigation Controller` because it doesn't seem to be necessary. Just create the controllers in storyboard like in my snapshot and see first.

Comment: @user2710855 that is a legitimate error above: you are sending `UINavigation Controller` a `mySwitsch` message that doesn't exist.

Comment: @user2710855 if you really want to keep your navigation controller, see my super super edit.

Comment: Finally!!!!!! Your super super edit worked fine! Thanks a lot !!!! Vielen vielen Dank! Danke auch das du so lange Geduld mit mir hattest :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an IBOutlet from you UISwitch to your settingsviewcontroller in your .h file and name it switcher. Next use this code to see if the switch is on or of:

```
 SecondViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
 BOOL onOrOff = switcher.on;
 if (onOrOff == YES) NSLog(@"Switch is on");
 if (onOrOff == NO) NSLog(@"Switch is off");
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to make a @property of the UISwitch variable in the SecondView. And then access it through SecondView variable